# Передача строкового литерала в функцию

Tags: c++, строки, c++11

Есть функция из сторонней библиотеки

```cpp
void test(LPOLESTR arg);
```

Описание функции менять не могу.

При передаче в нее строкового литерала

```cpp
test(L"Test");
```

получаю предупреждение

> ISO C++11 does not allow conversion from string literal to 'LPOLESTR' (aka 'wchar_t *')

Как корректно избавиться от предупреждения?

Comment: Привести строковый литерал к `LPOLESTR`? `test((LPOLESTR)L"Test");` Предупреждение возникает т.к. строковый литерал с припиской `L` это `const wchar_t*`, а `LPOLESTR` это `wchar_t*`.

Comment: Это должно быть не предупреждение, а ошибка. Чтобы избавиться от нее передавайте требуемый параметр функции. @ПавелЕриков Не стоит советовать всякую дичь.

Comment: Есть COM-интерфейс,, где  LPOLESTR   не wchar_t*? Вполне  может быть. Зато wchar_t* по любому преобразуется в  LPOLESTR, поэтому правильное преобразование const wchar_t* -> wchar_t*-> LPOLESTR , то есть:    `test((wchar_t*)(L"Test"))`

Comment: @user7860670 Я ничего не кому не советовал. Я написал комментарий, который может помочь решить проблему. И да лично у меня это решает проблему. Так что перед тем, как писать "_Не стоит советовать всякую **дичь**_", могли бы воспользоваться гуглом. Я заметил, что вы достаточно дерзки в своих высказывание и мне не понятно с чего это?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Я понимаю откуда растут ноги у предупреждения. Раз функция принимает указатель, то, вообще говоря, никто не мешает функции начать менять данные по этому указателю (если не ошибаюсь, то CreateProcess так делает). Так, что каст к неконстантному указателю - это просто попытка обмануть компилятор, но не убрать проблему. Решением будет malloc/copy/free. Вот мне интересно как єто красивее сделать на с++

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, что такое красивее? Для меня это  наиболее простым путем получать результат. В данном случаи я бы поступил как сказано в  комментарии  от user7860670   В явном преобразовании нет безопасности, но и нет никакого обмана.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков "_Я написал комментарий, который может помочь решить проблему_" и одновременно создать новую. Функции нужен указатель на неконстантные данные. Логично предположить, что функция может эти самые данные менять. Или вы в гугле нашли пруф, что функция из вопроса никогда так не поступит? :D

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл а автор писал где-то, про то, что она изменяет что-то? А если она что-то изменяет, то почему автор вопроса пытается изначально туда сразу передавать строковый литерал?? Я думаю если автор использует функцию, то он знает, что она делает. И если он решил передавать в нее строковый литерал, то я все чем смог помочь это преобразовать тип. И только потом автор в комментарии добавил, про то что ему не нужно, чтобы данные менялись. И да мне ничего не дает "_функция из сторонней библиотеки_", я к тому, что может создатель библиотеки не любит писать `const`, я то откуда знаю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создайте локальный массив, который будет находиться в стеке. И если его будут модифицировать, то исключения по памяти не будет.

```
wchar_t arr [ ] = L"Тест" ;
test ( arr ) ;
```